# Compute the minimum value of every row in a matrix using loops parallel with openmp C++

Tags: c++, loops, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to compute the minimum value of every row in a matrix in parallel using openmp c++ as follows:

```
// matrix Distf (float) of size n by n is declared before. 
vector<float> minRows;
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i=0; i < n; ++i){
     float minValue = Distf[i][0];
     #pragma omp parallel for reduction(min : minValue)
     for (j=1; j < n; ++j){
          if (Distf[i][j] < minValue){
                    minValue = Distf[i][j];
           }
     }
     minRows.push_back(minValue);
 }
```

So far the compiler does not raise any error but I wonder if this would give the correct answer as expect? Thanks

Comment: It would've been easier to help if you'd have supplied a minimal working example. That said, have you tried to just check? Even a 3x3 matrix gives a pretty clear answer in my minimal example.

Comment: Why do you parallelize the inner loop? It would much simpler to parallelize the outer one. As every iteration (thread) processes different rows, there is no race, no need for reduction and the code will be more efficient. The only constraint is that you cannot replace push_back() as the processing order is undefined and must replace it by an explicit write at minRows[i].

Comment: @AlainMerigot The inner loop is guarded from race conditions by the `reduction(min: minValue)` expression, if I understand it correctly - openMP seems to take care of creating local copies for each task. So while I agree insofar as either the matrix has to be huge, or the elements of the matrix be expensive to compare, it's not a data race there. The `push_back` is spot on, though.

Comment: @GeckoGeorge I did no say there is a race, and the reduction insures a proper behavior. What I mean is that if the parallelization is done on the outer loop no kind of race can happen, this kind of construct is not required, every thread works on its own data, the number of synchronizations is reduced and the parallelization and performances will be better.

Comment: @GeckoGeorge I already checked the instance of size 3.000 and it works fine. I have to use 'push_back' for a reason.

Comment: @ThomasEdison I saw a data race with 3x3 matrices - roughly every 1 in 4 times one of the lines was missing in `minRows`, because `push_back` is not thread safe. Not even as in "the order is undefined" (which is also true), but as in "data is missing". If you desperately need it, you'll have to guard it by mutex or something similar.

Comment: @GeckoGeorge Thanks alot. Can I avoid it using minRows[i] instead of push_back? The order does not matter for me because later I need to compute the top kth largest numbers from minRows.

Comment: Yes, Alain's suggestion makes sure that each element is accessed by it's own thread, so it's safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we talked about in the comments as an answer: Since I had to write some boilerplate anyway, I used ints as the type and avoided thinking about float problems at all:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    constexpr size_t n = 3;
    // dummy Distf (int) declared in lieu of matrix Distf 
    int Distf[n][n] = {{1,2,3},{6,5,4},{7,8,8}};

    //could be an array<int,n> instead
    vector<int> minRows(n);
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        int minValue = Distf[i][0];
// Alain Merigot argues this is a performance drag
//#pragma omp parallel for reduction(min : minValue)
        for (size_t j = 1; j < n; ++j){
            if (Distf[i][j] < minValue){
                minValue = Distf[i][j];
            }
        }
        //minRows.push_back(minValue) is a race condition!
        minRows[i] = minValue;
    }

    int k = 0;
    for(auto el: minRows){
        cout << "row " << k++ << ": " << el << '\n';
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

The inner loop normally doesn't need to be parallelized. I don't know how many cores you can use, but unless you're on a massively parallel system, think GPU-level of parallelism, the outer loop should either utilize all available cores already, or the problem just isn't big enough to matter. Starting more threads in either situation is a pessimization.